# Remember what user selected on previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

```js
tis is for the first page

<script>$(function() {
    $('#Gender').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.value);
    });
</script>

<script>$(function() {
    $('#men').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData1', this.value);
    });
</script>
<script>$(function() {
    $('#mtsm').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData2', this.value);
    });
</script>










this is for the next page 

<script>
  if(localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
        $('#Gender').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData'));
    }
});
</script>

<script>
  if(localStorage.getItem('todoData1')){
        $('#men').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData1'));
    }
});
</script>

<script>
  if(localStorage.getItem('todoData2')){
        $('#mtsm').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData2'));
    }
});
</script>
```

I would like to know how can I display something on the second page by remembering what the user chose on the first page. On the first page I have a drop down menu and the user has choices on what shirt they want the can pick between male female, long sleeve, short sleeve, and color when they choose one of these an image appears inside a div the image is the front part of the shirt. What I want is for site to remember what type and color shirt the user  chose and display the back part of the shirt of the same style and color without having a drop down menu. I have heard of using cookies but I don't know if that is efficient and I have no idea where to start.

```js
function fctCheck(gender) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(gender).style.display = "block";
}


$('#men').on('change', function() {
  $("#mtsm").css('display', (this.value == 'tsm') ? 'block' : 'none');
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function() {
    $('.container ').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image") + ')');
  });
  $('.colore').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').css('src', '');
    $('.container ').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image") + ')');
    $('.container7').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image-back") + ')');
  });
  $('#toggler').click(function() {
    var tmp = $('.container').css('background-image');
    $('.container').css('background-image', $('.container7').css('background-image'));

    $('.container7').css('background-image', tmp);
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="Gender" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
        <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
        <option value="men">Men</option>
        <option value="wemen">Wemen</option>
        <option value="girls">Girls</option>
        <option value="boys">boys</option>
    </select>  
    <br>
       <br>
    <select id="men" name="subselector" style="display:none">
      <option value="">Choose an item</option> 
      <option value="tsm">T-Shirt</option>
      <option value="lsm">long sleeve</option>
     <option value="tankm">Tank Top</option>
     <option value="fzhm">Full zip Hood</option>
     <option value="pohm">Pull over Hood</option>
     <option value="fzfm">Full zip Fleece</option>
     <option value="fm">Fleece</option>
    </select>  
 
    
    <select id="wemen" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="slw">short sleeve</option>
 
    </select>  
    
     <select id="girls" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="shortsg">shorts</option>
        
    </select>  
 <select id="boys" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="tshirtb">tshirt</option>
       
    </select>  
     <div style='display:none;' id="wsl">
                       <div class="colore white" data-image="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi.png">
                </div>
                <div class="colore black" data-image="http://mebe.co/ford">
                </div>
                <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://mebe.co/f150">
                </div>
                <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://mebe.co/yukon">
                </div>
                <div class="colore red" data-image="http://mebe.co/370z">
                </div>
            </div>
            
              <div style='display:none;' id="mtsm">
    <div class="colore white active" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/white.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/whiteback.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore black" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/black.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/whiteback.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/yellow.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/orange.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/orange.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/yellow.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore red" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/red.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/black.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you support older browser or not?

Comment: no i support ie 10+ why do you ask?

Comment: The answer below can be used. If you support older browser. You can put it on your url. So you can get it via javascript on the other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the javascript local storage object will serve this purpose quite well.

For example, whenever the user selects an option, set it as so...

```
localStorage.option1 = "wow cool option text here"
```

Then retrieve it on the next page with...

```
var option1 = localStorage.option1
```

Check this link out for more info 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**EDIT**
As pointed out by Herm Luna in the comments, this will not work in super old browsers, there is a table in the link I added that outlines this

Comment: It can be used if he doesn't support older browser. I mean ancient like IE8. Hahaha. Good answer tho.

Comment: @HermLuna ah fair point :) I've stopped supporting that far back so I didn't consider

Comment: i checked out the link above but i still have a question would this be in a separate script tag or would it be under the same  from the code that i entered.?

Comment: @loosemymind I would put in the change handler code for each of your select boxes. Think about it, when the gender select changes, you want to store gender right? And for men, the same? Just pop it in the change handler right alongside your original code, and call it from the next page :)

Comment: @NickWinner  for some reason this is not working i found another code similar to yours and i also cant seem to make it work i want to be able restrict the user to not choose any other option on page two because on the first page the options have already been chosen. does this make sense?  its hard for me to explain things im sorry

Comment: @loosemymind Which part isn't working? My approach to this problem would be to store the selected values in localStorage, grab them on the second page, and use them there. You could even use a span or a div tag and populate them with the values to let the user know what they've chosen

Comment: @NickWinner  i will understand if you dont want to help me anymore thank you for your time.

Comment: @loosemymind no you're good! You're on the right track, you say you don't want people to be able to change the input on the second page right? Once you've set the value, just add the disabled tag onto your select http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_disabled.asp Is that along the lines of what you're asking?

Comment: @NickWinner yes that is exactly what im asking thank you. i have the same code on the second page as the first page.

Comment: @loosemymind it seems to me that you don't even need a select box on the second page, do you? The only point of a select box would be to allow the user to change the value. What about just using a div tag with the value?

Comment: @NickWinner great idea,  no i do not need a select box on the second page i appreciate all your help thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Cookie is one way to look at it. On the other hand we can use localStorage. Setting items in localStorage is easier.

Another way to go is using url parameters. You can use query string to store info:

```
/?info1=foo&info2=bar
```

Accessing these info can be done both in server-side and client-side. You can use javascript to get these info, see this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)